# New domain not working on computer that purchased it

Tags: windows-7, ip, domain-name, hosts, local

I recently purchased a domain name from Hover.com for my website.

My nameservers have updated and everyone can access the site... except me.

Friends from across the US, local friends, other computers on same internet connection, phones, tablets on the same internet connection, etc all can access the site fine. The only exception seems to be my primary desktop which I purchased the domain name on. I am constantly redirected to Hover.com. If I use the command prompt to ping my domain I get a different IP than when others ping it.

The problem is consistent on chrome, internet explorer, and firefox.

Things I have tried:

Restarting modem and router.
Restarting computer.
Clearing all data, cache, history etc from my internet browser (chrome).
Flushing the DNS cache via command prompt with the "ipconfig /flushdns" command.
I have checked my hosts file for any irregularities.

I can view the site using a proxy and the domain name.

I am running windows 7. It has been over 24 hours since I've purchased and set up the host.

**Update:** My kindle fire which I have been using to view the site as I bug test since moving the files from my local machine to my host **has now started redirecting me to the hover.com site after about an hour of use**. I am now thinking my internet provider's nameservers may still need updating/be having issues. Other's on different internet connections can still access the site fine after multiple attempts over a good stretch of time. Everyone in my household/access to my internet connection is asleep and I do not have access to other devices to test. I will be going to sleep and maybe the issue will resolve itself. Or at least I hope.

**Update 11:05 8/27/13:** My kindle now continues to take me to hover.com, I turned off my modem and router while I slept so they were un-active for 8 hours. I don't see why my kindle would take me to my host then randomly stop. **I think this is now a nameserver issue and the question is closed until further notice.** I don't know how to close the question since this is my first time on this site and I do not see an option to do so.

Comment: I'd try using nslookup (DNS tool built into Windows). If that gives you the right IP, that means it probably is not a DNS issue. Then maybe try a tracert? This is a bit bizarre if you have indeed cleared everything.

Comment: Check if this machine is using a different nameserver from other machines.

Comment: I suggest doing some diagnostics and reporting back

Comment: it's also worth double-checking your local `hosts` file in case something odd is going on there.

Comment: Try manually switching nameservers to something else, for instance Google's: `8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a browser hijack, a virus or spyware has taken over the PC, update and scan the PC's AV and Anti spyware app.